# Customized Parallel sets in R using ggparallel

Tags: r, data-visualization

[image]

I am trying to create similar chart in R using ggparallel but I can't get the gaps between the values for e.g in this case between "Yes" and "No" in my visualization. I am not sure if it is possible in ggparallel or would I have to write a seperate customized function for this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested and willing to consider a non-`ggparallel` option, I just built an `htmlwidget` for parallel sets in `R`.  See [example vignette](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/parsetR/)

```
# devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/parsetR")
library(parsetR)

# using defaults
parset(Titanic)
```